# Will entifty-framework-core auto fit row_lock or table_lock to mysql?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core

I am using mysql with `entityframework` core.

> **1. Table is as following**:

```
create table `device_power_duration` (
`Id` varchar(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
`DeviceId` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`StartTime` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
`PowerSupplyDuration` datetime(6) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

> **2. Operations**

There will be 1000 request to update a table every 30 seconds.
Every request will do the following work:

- If `deviceId` is not exist then create it.
- If `deviceId` is exist then update the `PowerSupplyDuration` column of this deviceId.

The operations for every request is just like following code:

```
var device =_context.Devices.AsNoTracking().Where(x=>x.DeviceId=="xxxxx").First();
if(device==null)
{
    //create a device
}
else
{
    //update the device
}
```

> **3. Questions:**

- What lock should I use? row-lock or table-lock?
- Will the `entityframeworkcore` auto fit the lock?
- will a dead-lock occur under `1000 requests` sitation?

Comment: A lot of things will affect mysql's lock. For example,  `engine type`, `query sql`, `table structure` and so on. You couldn't ask if 1000 reuests will cause a dead-lock without any other detail information. Please provide some examples and more detials, like what engine you used, what your table structure is, and what  your queries like. Ohterwise, it will be very hard to help you for others.

Comment: I updated it thank you @Zhiyong

Comment: please provide your index information, I guess `id` is your primary index and `deviceid` is another index. is that correct?  BTW, is your `transaction isolation levels` is RR?

Comment: How do you determine if `deviceId` is existed or not? Do you add unique index for `deviceId`? Or you do it in your app?

Comment: @Zhiyong I updated it.Yes deviceId is the index and id is the key and primary index.

Comment: I am sorry I do not know transaction isolation levels and do not set it.

Comment: Use `show variables like "%isolation%";` to get your isolation level. From your example code, I'm afraid you will not update existed device's `powersupplyduration`, because on multiple thread env, there could be several thread execute device id detect and result is null, they will insert into databases if device id is not unique key. How about this situation? Is that OK for you?

Comment: @Zhiyong device id is not unique because there will be many records of one device id and I will only want to update the incomplete one which powersupplyduration is to be updating..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219324/discussion-between-zhiyong-and-liang-good).

Comment: if you feel my answer is helpful, please vote up it as well~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### answers for Q1 and Q3

**Q1**: I suggest you to use innodb, and innodb will manage row-level locks for you automatically

**Q3**: I'm afraid deadlock will occur base on your current workflow and table structure. Please see more details below.

Actually there are several situations I could tell will cause deadlock. Let's begin base on the following test data:

### Test Data and Tables, Business Workflow

```
create table `device_power_duration` (
`Id` varchar(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
`DeviceId` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`StartTime` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
`PowerSupplyDuration` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
index idx_dev_id (`DeviceId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

insert into `device_power_duration` (Id, DeviceId, StartTime, PowerSupplyDuration)
VALUES ('1', '1', now(), now()),
       ('3', '3', now(), now()),
       ('5', '5', now(), now()),
       ('7', '7', now(), now());
```

WorkFlow is as following:

```
public bool UpdateDeviceRecord(Guid id,bool deviceIsRunning)
{
    var list = _context.Ddj_Device_Records.AsNoTracking()
                    .Where(x => x.DeviceNo == id.ToString() && (DateTime.Now - x.UpdatedTime).TotalMinutes > 30).ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        list[i].PowerSupplyFinished = true;
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
    var record = _context.Ddj_Device_Records.AsNoTracking()
        .Where(x => x.DeviceNo == id.ToString() && (DateTime.Now - x.UpdatedTime).TotalMinutes < 30).FirstOrDefault();
    if (record == null)
    {
        //create a new record
    }
    else
    {
        record.UpdatedTime = DateTime.Now;
        if (!deviceIsRunning)
        {
             record.PowerSupplyFinished = false;
        }
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

### Concurrent insert with the same `Id` and `DeviceId`

Actually there will be caused by primary key `Id`.

session1 execute rollback instead of commit after insert. Then a deadlock will occur. This rollback may cause by exception in your application or other abnormal situations and it's related to your mysql framework.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
session1                        |   session2                        |   session3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
insert (Id='2', DeviceId='2')   |                                   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                |   insert (Id='2', DeviceId='2')   |
                                |   Blocked                         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                |                                   |   insert (Id='2', DeviceId='2')
                                |                                   |   Blocked
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rollback                        |                                   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                |   Success                         |   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                |                                   |   deadlock
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The deadlock details infor is as following:

```
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 4274, ACTIVE 12 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 4 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 104, OS thread handle 139681802041088, query id 24311 172.22.0.1 root update
/* ApplicationName=PyCharm 2019.1.1 */ insert into `device_power_duration` (Id, DeviceId, StartTime, PowerSupplyDuration)
VALUES ('2', '2', now(), now())
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 116 page no 3 n bits 72 index PRIMARY of table `test`.`device_power_duration` trx id 4274 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 6; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 33; asc 3;;
 1: len 6; hex 00000000109f; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex f3000001e7011a; asc        ;;
 3: len 1; hex 33; asc 3;;
 4: len 8; hex 99a70e37b7000000; asc    7    ;;
 5: len 8; hex 99a70e37b7000000; asc    7    ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 4275, ACTIVE 9 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
4 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 105, OS thread handle 139681803122432, query id 24321 172.22.0.1 root update
/* ApplicationName=PyCharm 2019.1.1 */ insert into `device_power_duration` (Id, DeviceId, StartTime, PowerSupplyDuration)
VALUES ('2', '2', now(), now())
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 116 page no 3 n bits 72 index PRIMARY of table `test`.`device_power_duration` trx id 4275 lock mode S locks gap before rec
Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 6; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 33; asc 3;;
 1: len 6; hex 00000000109f; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex f3000001e7011a; asc        ;;
 3: len 1; hex 33; asc 3;;
 4: len 8; hex 99a70e37b7000000; asc    7    ;;
 5: len 8; hex 99a70e37b7000000; asc    7    ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 116 page no 3 n bits 72 index PRIMARY of table `test`.`device_power_duration` trx id 4275 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 6; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 33; asc 3;;
 1: len 6; hex 00000000109f; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex f3000001e7011a; asc        ;;
 3: len 1; hex 33; asc 3;;
 4: len 8; hex 99a70e37b7000000; asc    7    ;;
 5: len 8; hex 99a70e37b7000000; asc    7    ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

### Concurrent update record in different order

> **Situation 1**

Base on current business workflow, MySQL sorts the records however it wants without any guarantee of consistency. Therefore, two concurrent thread may update the same `list`(var) with different order. Then deadlock occur.

More details about the default order is [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/what-is-the-default-order-of-records-for-a-select-statement-in-mysql)

> **Situation 2**

Even all record had been sorted by id, there could be deadlock, just like the following situations:
The key point is session1's `record` may become to session2's list elements because of time is always changing.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
session1                                            |   session2                                            | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
list=(id[5,7])                                      |                                                       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
update PowerSupplyFinished when(id in [5,7])        |                                                       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
record=4                                            |                                                       | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                    |   list=(id[4,5,7])                                    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                    |   update PowerSupplyFinished when(id in [4,5,7])      |  
                                                    |   block(hold id=4 lock, required id=5&7 locks)        | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
update PowerSupplyFinished when(id=4)               |                                                       |
deadlock(required id=4 lock, hold id=5&7 locks)     |                                                       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Suggestions

1. Keep your transaction small
2. Make sure update sequence are the same in different threads.
3. Add another auto increasement unsigned int type column `pid` as the primary key. That would benifit insert performance.

More could refer to this [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlocks-handling.html)